# Not allowing space in password field when using authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using authlogic for my user login functionality in my Rails app. But authlogic allows space in password and my application doesn't require this. So how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear whether you are concerned with validating password formats at user creation time or at authentication time. You might find the answer to this question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186831/validating-password-format-in-authlogic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to define your password rules.

```
validates_format_of :password, :with => /{regular expression here}/, :if => :require_password?, :message => "Must not contain any spaces!"
```